# SSAS OLAP Cube: Row level security with Cube Roles

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, olap, row-level-security

I got a multidimensional OLAP-Cube that attracts my MS SQL Server Database. By now, there was no need for row level security.
Now, we would like to grant access to different sales representatives with Excel-Sheets that have a Live-conneciton to Analysis Services - so every salesman could evaluate the revenues in his sales territory.

This is my data example:

[Product table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0yLg.png)

[Customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UbcG.png)

I build a role to restrict the access for the first salesman by customizing the access to dimension data:

[new role in my cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWD4s.png)

Then I tested my new role and got the following result:

[result of product table after restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxlmA.png)

[result of customer table after restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA2Ow.png)

The restricted role still can see the whole data of the product table and the total amount of the customer table, although the totals are disabled:

[disabled totals in Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MeI7.png)

Does anyone one my mistake I did when setting up the new role?

The result, I would like to see after restriction should be this way:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN3YB.png)

I hope that someone can help me despite the small amount of information.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this if you tick "[Enable Visual Totals](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/05/show-correct-totals-when-using-ssas-role-security/)" at the bottom of the popup:
[image]